# Do churches host distinctive, special services on Christmas, Christmas eve, and Easter?

Tags: church-local, christmas, easter

I have read before that some (nominal) Christians only attend worship services on Christmas and Easter. Are there anything *special* about those two holidays that compel them to attend church during Christmas and Easter? What do the churches do exactly that might convince people to attend church on only those days?

I know that stores hold big sales on those days, which may attract people to go shopping and buy merchandise.

Comment: What kind of answers are you looking for other than "Yes"?

Answer (score 4):

Typically, yes, most denominations how special services on Christmas eve, and some, possibly, on Christmas day.  (More details coming.)

In Catholic Churches, there is the [Midnight Mass](http://www.aquinasandmore.com/catholic-articles/the-tradition-of-midnight-mass/article/119/sort/relevance/productsperpage/12/layout/grid/currentpage/1/keywords/christmas,%20mass).  There's also [Christmas Vespers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vespers) for several denominations including the Catholic Church, Eastern Orthodox, Lutheran, and Anglican Churches.

[The LDS Church has some unique Christmas traditions](http://lds.about.com/od/christmas/tp/lds_christmas_traditions.htm), including visting Templa Square at Christmas, and watching the Church's annual "First Presidency Christmas Devotional" which is broadcast from the Conference Center (at Temple Square) to church buildings worldwide.

Other denominations have special services as well.  Typical Baptist Christmas services, for example, involve plays and singing by the kids in the Church.  It tends to draw family members that do not attend.

Christmas is the celebration of the Lord and Savior - the entire reason for the existence of the Church in the first place, so it kind of makes sense that there would be some special pomp and circumstance surrounding the celebration.  The same can be said for Easter.

As for why people visit church on Christmas, that's far more personal and individual.  As such it's probably not on-topic to speculate, but reasons I've heard and my own reasons when I wasn't' a Christian included:

- It helps you get into the Christmas spirit.
- Tradition
- From an atheist perspective: It's a nice thing to do to show support for that Christian relative of yours that's always bugging you to get saved and turn your life over to Jesus.  it's only an hour or so and it tends to seem to make them happy to have you there, so why not?
- Maybe people already are in the Christmas spirit, and therefore are more willing to go.

I'm sure there are dozens of other reasons.  Again, that's all unique and individual, and hard to answer.

Comment: So, other worship services are not *interesting* enough, huh?

Comment: That's subjective.  Other services are interesting to me. But for me, Christmas is more.  It's awesome to me to think of God humbling Himself to be born a fragile, innocent baby, in such lowly conditions, knowing full well that this is the beginning of His earthly incarnation, which would ultimately end in a torturous, horrific death.  The love inherent in such an awesome chain events is staggering, and Christmas is a reminder of that love.  But again, that's subjective.  Just why it's special to me.

Answer (score 0):

YES

The services on these special days are special and distinct from other days, especially on Christmas.

The program on these special days include many exciting events. The kind of events differ from one church to another, one denomination to another. Some of them are -

1. Exchanging or distributing gifts on Christmas
2. Beautiful songs presented by special singers, choirs or bands
3. Beautiful decorations. Churches are decorated specially on Christmas
4. Well prepared skids, dramas and other entertainments
5. Games and other exciting activities
6. A special feast prepared for the special day

And much more...

Because of all these special things on these special days, even those who are lazy to attend churches on other days want to attend the church. Believe it or not, if your church has an average of 100 members attending the church regularly, expect to see at least 200 members on Christmas! Sometimes, the church will encourage the members to invite guests on Christmas.

Christmas is a big day. People are preparing for Christmas one or two months in advance. The church members are busy practicing songs, skids and choirs. Every one is active on Christmas time. Why would anyone want to miss this beautiful day?

Answer (score -1):

Nominal Christians = Christians in name only, not (yet) transformed by the renewing of their mind by the presence of Christ and His Gospel in their lives.

Besides the festivities around Christmas that attracted these group of people the same way the stores attract us with their light displays and big discounts, there is also an aspect of guilt in play here.

Christians who are not motivated enough to attend the church regularly often feel guilty about it at times.  Therefore Christmas and Easter are seen as the two occasions when they can somehow "redeem" their guilty feelings.

Comment: At least be reasonable and state why you give my answer a -1. I don't care about the number, but I would like to learn about the perspective that compelled you to disagree with me.